# Problem with manifest Line 1 Column 1 Syntax Error No resource with given URL found

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, manifest

I am having an issue once the react app site is deployed with the manifest being blank.  When running on localhost, it displays normally under the Chrome dev console under Application.  Here is my line with reference to it on my index.html.

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
```

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "short_name": "Test",
  "name": "Test React App",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "example-192x192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "example-512x512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

I have spent a ton of time trying to understand why the manifest is completely blank when deployed but does not have any errors when running locally.  From the docs, it seems it should work.  Am I missing something?  If it helps, I am deploying over AWS.  Any information would be helpful.

Also, I adjusted my index.html to look like href="manifest.json" as well

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add `crossorigin="use-credentials"` to get rid of the error. My `manifest.json` is located in the public folder.

`<link rel="manifest" crossorigin="use-credentials" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />`

Answer (score 0):

If you used create-react-app and then used some tool to generate your favicon and html meta tags then becareful not to make a duplicate of `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>`. For me, this is what cause the error.